# Is there such a C++ feature: "const scope" in method definitions?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there is a safety feature to restrict a scope of a class method definition to allow disallow modifying access to `*this`. See this pseudo-code:

```
class C{
 void method();
 void const_method() const {
     // do const stuff here
 }
};

void C::method(){
    const_method();
}
```

Now instead of calling `const_method();` I would directly have a scope which only allows const access, i.e. which only allows code that would also be valid within the `const_method` definition like this:

```
void C::method(){
    // {  "const scope"
    // instead of const_method();
    // do const stuff directly here
    // }
}
```

I know that I can just call a const method but when I like to modify outer local variables in the const scope I would have to make them be returned from the const function or use a reference or pointer parameter as a workaround. So I am wondering if there exists a language feature to have "const scopes"?

My goal is to have peace of mind in some sections of the code, the compiler shall verify that I do not modify the class instance in sections of code where I do not intend this.

**EDIT**
I have seen in the comments that I can use `const C* const_this{this};` But of course this does not prevent me from modifying `*this` when I forget to use `const_this`. I have the feeling that it could be done with a lambda thich captures all locals and captures `*this` as const somehow. How could this be done?

Comment: Why not providing a `private` `const` function call there?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I could as I wrote above. But when I want to have side effects to other local variables in `method()`s definition I would have to use the above described workarounds (return them from the private const function or have them as pointer/reference parameters). When there are a lot, it would make me "fight against the language" I want to clean up a large messy code section.

Comment: Half measures is `const C* const_this{this};`. Calling non-const on `const_this` is an error.  What you can't do is 'hide' `this` in an inner scope.

Comment: Which language exactly does have this "const scope" feature?

Comment: I find this level of `const` fanaticism to be absurd. If you can't tell whether a single block in your function mutates state, then you should refactor. Otherwise, trust the reader to have a basic level of comprehension.

Comment: @digito_evo I found this idea useful but I don't know any language supporting it.

Comment: I don't understand what "outer local variables" are in this context, and why they pose a problem.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I mean local variables within the method definition of `C::method()` which I want to modify within the const scope. To modify them with a `private` `const` function I would need to pass them as a parameter. When there are many, I have to use many parameters of pack them into a struct that I pass by reference to the `private` `const` function.

Comment: There's no such thing in C++, C++ does not work this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a immediately invoked lambda, though you still have to capture the local variables explicitly:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    int member = 42;
    void bar() {
        int local_var = 42;
        [const_obj=const_cast<const foo&>(*this),&local_var](){
            //member = 2;           // error: this is not captured
            //const_obj.member = 2; // error: const_obj is read-only 
            const_obj.const_method();
            std::cout << const_obj.member;
        }();
    }
    void const_method() const {};
};
```

However, I somewhat agree with comments. Your approach of simply calling `const_method` is ok, while your argument against it (Needing to pass paramteters and return values) is a matter of design that can be solved in different less arcance ways. The reluctance to pass parameters and return values around can lead to the most absurde constructs, while simply passing parameters and return values around is typically the more clear, readable and simpler code.

PS: There is a way to get somewhat the opposite of what you ask for. I am not recommending it, hence I will only outline it: In the example above you could make `bar` call a private `bar() const`. Because `bar() const` is only called from non-const `bar()` you can safely cast away constness to get a mutable reference to the current object that can be restricted to a narrow scope. Though, if you aim for "peace of mind" then this approach is not the way to go.

Comment: I think you are right. But it would be even cleaner if C++ supported such a feature of `const scope`, it seems easy to implement and after all there are much more useless features supported such as rarely used inheritance modes.

Comment: @phinz the "const scope feature" does already exist, it is const member functions

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is, using shadowing and static member functions. Your compiler should be configured to warn about this, so you would have to deactivate it specifically for this particular case.

```
class C{
 static void method(C& self) {
   // non-const stuff with self
   {
     C& ncvSelf = self;
     C const& self = ncvSelf; // intentional shadowing of self
     // const stuff with self
   }
   // non-const stuff with self
 }
};
```

The reason you have to use the self idiom is because you cannot declare a `this` variable to shadow the actual `this` pointer.